# Add file to ISO with Rock Ridge extensions

Tags: c#, linux, windows, iso, live-cd

I have a ISO creates on linux, which contains files for a bootable livecd system. The ISO uses Rock Ridge to preserve linux permissions.

I need to modify this ISO file on a windows system (without booting a linux VM), how would i go around adding a file to the ISO without loosing linux symlinks and the linux permissions?

This is part of a larger .NET application, so i am looking for a console tool or a .NET library to facilitate the modification of the iso.

I already tried the following:

- Manually extracted and recreated the iso using mkisofs from cygwin. (Problem: looses rock ridge informaiton)
- Modify the ISO using C# and the [DiscUtils library](http://discutils.codeplex.com/). (Problem: DistUtils only supports reading Rock Ridge - not writing)

Comment: IT only supports reading as ISO was designed as a write ***once*** file system.

Comment: Put a dummy file with a weel known "signature" inside the iso, replace the dummy file byte by byte with the variable data and softmount or untar it when booting from the CD.

Answer (score 1):

Using java you can Use JIIC(Java ISO Image Creator) [JIIC](http://jiic.berlios.de/)
Here you have to use jiic api jiic jar and sabre jar file 
You can get sample [program to create iso file](https://github.com/stephenc/java-iso-tools/blob/master/iso9660-writer/ISOtest.java)